# Tomcat deployement issue in a Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

i have tried the possible solutions mentioned here. still i am not able to findout where my code is going wrong. the below is my plugin which i added in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>myserver</server>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my **settings.xml** is like

```
<server>
  <id>myserver</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

my **tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>

    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat" username="tomcat"/>
    <user password="admin" roles="manager-gui" username="admin"/>
    <user password="password" roles="admin,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" username="username"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

i have tried the url `http://localhost:8080/manager/text` in my browser. it is not running. can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting when executing Maven?

Comment: thanks for your response tschaible....this is the error....Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project app-personaltitania-web: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you verify if Tomcat is up and running on port 8080? Connection refused usually means that the client (in this case maven) couldn't even make a connection on the port.  Usually you'll see this if Tomcat is not running, not running on port 8080, or some firewall rule is preventing access.

Comment: `Connection refused: connect` you have a problem with your connection : maybe a proxy or something like this

Comment: thank you tschaible and hohenheim.....issue was solved....it was the problem with tomcat only:)